# UIButtons covered by footer and header in messages extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

[image: buttons covered by message sender area]

How can I make the uibuttons not covered by the message sender overlay and header? This is a message extension and turning under top bars off does not seem to change anything. There is a uibutton which is covered by the header which I would like to be shown below the header.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose this without further information, so to save time I'm going to assume you're using view controller containment to present your data. (If not, you really ought to – see Apple's example code for Messages extensions, because it's exactly what they do.)

When you add your child view controller to the parent, you should use anchors to ensure it stays below the top bar, regardless of how big it is. You could try using either this:

```
childVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Or this:

```
childVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```